# SAS: Predefine table name in 'proc sql' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

In SAS I have a simple proc SQL statement in which I will control table to get data from by a predefined variable.

I want to keep the 'Data sorurce' and 'Initial Catalog' catalog fixed and define it in my proc sql but I want to declare the table beforehand.

In my code below I want to predefine where the '*' are

```
proc sql;
   ...
   select ...
   From *
    ...
quit;
```

I have tried the following wothout luck:

```
%let sqltable = "[my_table]";

proc sql;
   ...
   select ...
   From &sqltable.
    ...
quit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless absolutely necessary, don't quote your macro variables; if you need quotes, quote them when you resolve them. In this case, you don't need quotes at all.

```
%let sqltable = [my_table];

proc sql;
   ...
   select ...
   From &sqltable.
    ...
quit;
```